# Delay in button activation in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a grid that's is data bound and two buttons that I make visible after the grid is data bound.

```
this.GridView1.DataSource = ReturnReportdata();
this.GridView1.DataBind();            
this.btnExportToExcel.Visible = true;
this.btnPrint.Visible = true;
```

The data set contains a lot of records (500 records at least). And even though the two buttons are visible and grid populated, it takes about 5 seconds for the buttons to actually become live. Until such time they are dead (no hover effect). How do I overcome this.

Comment: @Ignaus, the code in the question happens before the HTML is even sent to the browser so re-ordering will do nothing.

Comment: @JonP Oh I'm sorry, for some reason I was under the impression that it was a Forms application. Nevermind. :)

Comment: @voddy, do you have any javascript operating on the gridview? Anthing that might be blocking the UI? Do you get the same problem across browsers?

Comment: No Javascript. Plain and simple GridView. Yes on all browsers.